pygam - how can I add rug plot (ticks to show density of datapoints) on x-axis in a partial dependence plot?
I have created a GAM model, using the pygam library, lets call my model "gam". I am making partial dependence plots from my model to show the partial effects from each variable using  code below in Python.
From experience using R software, partial dependence plots show a rug plot at the x-axis, showing the distribution of data points for each variable. It appears quite automatic in R whenever I plot the partial dependence plots.
However, in Python, using the pygam library, my partial dependence plots do not show the 'rug' or distribution of data points on the x-axis. Is there a way I can add this in when plotting from pygam in Python?
Here is the code I am using in Python to plot the partial dependence plots from my 'gam' model:
Make the partial dependence plots.
screenshot of code on my IDE
# gam model code above

# PLOT TRIAL

# Set up the figure
titles = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
# plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (25, 25)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 20), layout='constrained')
axs = axs.flatten()

# Make the partial dependence plots.

for i in range(0,12,1):
    XX = gam.generate_X_grid(term=i)
    axs[i].plot(XX[:, i], gam.partial_dependence(term=i, X=XX), c='dimgrey', ls='solid', lw=2)
    axs[i].plot(XX[:, i], gam.partial_dependence(term=i, X=XX, width=.95)[1], c='cornflowerblue', ls='dotted',lw=1.5)
    axs[i].set_ylim(-2,2)
    #axs[i].set_xlim(8,11)
    axs[i].set_xlabel(titles[i], fontsize=12)
    axs[i].set_ylabel("Partial Effect", fontsize=12)
    axs[i].set_title("")
    axs[i].axhline(y=0.0, c="crimson",linewidth=0.6,zorder=0,ls=':')
fig.savefig('partial_plot_from_python.eps', format='eps', dpi=600)

I expect the code to produce something similar to the figure shown (done in R, see the rug showing the density distribution of data points on the x-axis).
partial dependence plot showing x-axis data density rugs
